# C++/Visual Studio - _wgetcwd returns project folder not application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

As far as I understand `_wgetcwd` returns pointer to string(wchar_t*) to application directory(directory from exe is).

When I run Visual Studio(2012) debug `_wgetcwd` returns project directory not the one that contains executed exe file.

Is it expected? Is there any other prefered method that returns directory containing ran executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't return the directory where the program resides, it returns the process *current working directory*, which may in some cases be the same to that of the location of the program.

You can change the project settings to set the working directory.

Comment: Thanks works gr8, but can I trust `_wgetcwd` method when run from exe/shortcut/commandline to point to directory containing executable?

Comment: @EOG Shortcuts can have a custom working directory set. If you run from a command-line window, the working directory is the one where you are in when starting the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetModuleFileName.